Google Cloud Speech-To-Text tagging requests for billing purposes
I am looking to reduce the amount of hassle we get by managing multiple customers within the same app. Today we're using service account JSON files for authentication, one file for each customer. We do this to separate billing accordingly. This basically means that each customer is its own project within the Google Cloud Console.
My wish is that we would have one account, and one JSON file for all customers. But in order to successfully to this and track the cost within the Google Console Billing I need each request to be tagged so that it can be filtered. This is a requirement from billing & management to be able to track and see the cost of each project/customer.
Here's an example of our authentication and Speech-2-Text request.
from google.oauth2  import service_account
from google.cloud import speech

auth = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("project-A-Customer10050.json")
client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=auth)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        enable_automatic_punctuation=False,
        audio_channel_count=1,
        language_code="en-US",
        model="default",
        speech_contexts=[{'phrases': ["Hint X", "Hint Y"]}]
)

client.recognize(request={"config": config, "audio": "audio.wav"})

Does anyone know if this can be achieved? Or suggest an alternative solution to our problem?

Distributing Service Account keys is almost always a bad idea. Service Account keys are bearer tokens. If a customer shares a key that you've given them, you'll be challenged to detect|stop this. If you replace keys issued per customer with one key, you compound your problems. At least keys issued per customer allow you to disambiguate keys (remember they don't identify customers who'll be sharing them) but using labels is trivially manipulated. Service Accounts (without keys) should be used (essentially) to identify processes that you own, control and run on your Google Cloud projects.

I suspect (without knowing more) that you should migrate to an auth (authentication+authorization) system (for authentication e.g. Identity Platform) that uniquely identifies human users within your customers that your authorize (IIUC you'll need to roll-your-own or use a 3rd-party for authorization) to your app (which would use a Service Account identity). You'd be able to use claims for users, customers and more to help e.g. label Google API calls for your billing.
